# If $T$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$, is $H(\theta\mid x) = H(\theta\mid T(x))$?

Tags: entropy, sufficient-statistics, mutual-information

I was trying to prove that sufficient statistics attain equality in the data processing inequality by a slightly different route than I usually see, and came across an odd expression. (I care more about understanding the odd expression than about proving the data processing inequality).

So if we have $\theta \longrightarrow X \longrightarrow T(X)$, the data processing inequality gives us

$$I(\theta;X) \ge I(\theta;T(X))\tag{1}$$

and expanding out into entropies yields $H(\theta) - H(\theta\mid X) \ge H(\theta) - H(\theta\mid T(X))$, which yields $$H(\theta\mid X) \le H(\theta\mid T(X))\tag{2}$$

So $(1)$ attains equality iff $(2)$ does. But how on earth do I even interpret $(2)$? $T(X)$ is generally a non-injective mapping, and so it seems very strange to me that a non-injective mapping (which should strictly decrease discrete entropy) could possibly lead to an equality.

I was trying to manipulate the Neyman-Fisher factorization to try and flip into the form of $(2)$, but to no avail.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is true that if $T$ is sufficient, then $$H(\theta | x) = H(\theta|T(x))$$.

From the definition of sufficiency, we have that $$P(x|T(x), \theta) = P(x|T(x))$$.

And now

$$P(\theta | x) = \frac{P(x, \theta)}{P(x)} = \frac{P(x, T(x), \theta)}{P(x, T(x))} = \frac{P(x|T(x), \theta)P(\theta, T(x))}{P(x|T(x))P(T(x))}$$

Now we use the above fact to simplify:

$$\frac{P(x|T(x), \theta)P(\theta, T(x))}{P(x|T(x))P(T(x))} = \frac{P(\theta, T(x))}{P(T(x))} = P(\theta | T(x))$$

Since $H$ is a function of $P$ we obtain the result.